# Try to create Android app in Visual studio 2015 Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create new android app project in Visual studio 2015 with xamatin, but when i click button OK, it alway show error

> Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown

Then, nothing happen!

Please help me to solve this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm try to uninstalling Xamarin and install again with exacly Android SDK path. If you see this problem, remember:
 - Uninstall Xamarin
 - install again
 - Choose exactly Android SDK path

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit generic but did you install the latest version on Java JDK?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem (on windows 10) because I have installed Xamarin before Visual Studio 2015. Uninstall Xamarin and install it again with the same ndk folder solved the problem.

Thanks

Comment: I have got : Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown when I tried to create a new android project.

Comment: That's why the question of Social code was generic... Because the problem is generic.